What should we do about the proliferation of unanswered questions?
Perusing other SE sites at a similar stage to ours, I've noticed they generally have answered percentages as high as 98-99%. Our site has a number of questions with quite a few up-votes yet no answers. What can we do to improve the user experience for newcomers and potential users in this regard? Users will quickly give up on us if they see that the community is unable to find answers to good questions. 

Considering the unanswered questions:
There are currently 34 with no upvoted answers:

https://quant.stackexchange.com/unanswered

And 25 with no answers at all:

https://quant.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

In addition to Robert's suggestion of publicizing these questions, assuming they are interesting, it's also a good idea to edit these unanswered questions and possibly comment on them. How can they be improved to be more clear and answerable?

+1, I think that just give a comment should be useful to move from the dead point.

Having 93% questions answered is admirable, but this community should be able to get that up there to about 97-100%!
The obvious way to service those unanswered questions is to go right now and check the 'unanswered' tab; Dig in, research, and answer those questions.
But longer term, keep using your social bookmarking tools. Pick a few questions and tweet them out as a call for experts! 
People love to show off, and a particularly intriguing question is irresistible!
This is a great opportunity to attract some great new users who will add value for years to come.




